# Configuring Apache2 /etc/mime.types to display .pgm images

Tags: apache-http-server, mime-types

I'm trying to display a .pgm image on my Apache2 server, however I can't seem to get it working. I've edited my `/etc/mime.types` file to include the line `image/x-portable-graymap pgm`, but it still doesn't work. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

try add that to httpd.conf

```
 AddType image/x-portable-graymap .pgm
```

Comment: How does the dot help?